# Is it possible to pass smarty functions into json html output?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, smarty

Trying to implement infinite scroll, with php, smarty and jquery ajax. As I understood best way to do so and not load server much is getting response as json formatted data, and do the all process on the client side. The thing is that I would like to pass smarty functions in that.
Just a piece of code with comments for you to understand what I mean:

```
$.each(data.content, function(key, value ){
if(value.comment !=''){

//When it comes to date, smarty is working and is implementing date_format
html += '<div class="timeline-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 
{'+value.date+'|date_format:"%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p"}</div>';
html += '</div>';

//But when it comes to comment itself, smarty functions are not working
html += '<p>{'+value.comment+'|smarty_modifier_autolink|nl2br|mention}</p>';
}
}
```

In second example with comment all I get in browser is `+value.comment+` instead of the comment itself.
I'm not strong with `json` or `javascript` in general, maybe there is some other way to render html to make it possible to use `smarty` functions? Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you write this on client side you will not be able to process the generated HTML through smarty again...

Comment: How is the generated HTML code processed?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand that question. What do you mean?

Comment: Where does the variable html go to? When is this JS code executed? Normally you have a template file which smarty will render. How is it done in your environment? Please give more information about your setup.

Comment: What are the contents of `value.date` and `value.comment`? Maybe `value.date` represents a smarty function/plugin and `value.comment` contains a variable string?

Comment: No, these are rows I get from db via php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `value.comment` just needs quotes:

```
html += '<p>{"'+value.comment+'"|smarty_modifier_autolink|nl2br|mention}</p>';
```

Have a look at this: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifiers.tpl

Normally after `{` there should be a smarty plugin, php variable or smarty command. If you want to add a modifier to a content string then you have to surround it by quotes.

Comment: Anyway, I accept your answer cuz this actually did the job though I can't apply my custom made functions. But maybe this will be really helpful to someone else. For now, I decided to stick to classical approach of making infinite scroll

Comment: Why aren't the modifiers working? What error do you see? Maybe you have to nest some curly braces like so `{{"somecontent"|smarty_modifier_autolink}|nl2br}`